# Powershell scripting - searching for string in files recursively using regex and outputting regex groups to file

Tags: powershell, select-string

I am recursively searching all files in a specified folder using regex.  These are icons (fontawesome) that are being used and I want to create a list of each that I use in my project.  They are in the format `fa(l, r, s, d, or b) fa-(a-z and -)`.  My script below is working and outputs each it finds in a new line.  If you noticed I grouped the first and second part of the regex though... how can I reference and ouput those groups rather than the whole match as it is currently?

```
$input_path = 'C:\Users\Support\Downloads\test\test\'
$output_file = 'results.txt'
$regex = '(fa[lrsdb]{1}) (fa-[a-z-]+)'
Get-ChildItem $input_path -recurse | select-string -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

An example results.txt would be something like :

```
far fa-some-icon
fal fa-some-icon2
far fa-something-else
fas fa-another-one
```

I want to be able to reference each part independently so say I could return 'fa-some-icon far' instead plus as I add more to this script it will come in handy being able to reference them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Value` property of a `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` object from `Select-String` will contain the whole line that contains the match. To access just the match or individual groups of the match, use the `Groups` property and its `Value` property respectively.

Change this line:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem $input_path -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

To the following line to get your desired output:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem $input_path -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Groups[0].Value } > $output_file
```

Or to the following line to get the output with both matching groups reversed:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem $input_path -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % {"$($_.Groups[2].Value) $($_.Groups[1].Value)"} > $output_file
```